# Issue with Infering attribures from master if child entity does not have them in TypeDB

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Hi I'm having the following issue.

In my database there are some entities (requirement) that have a set of attributes (name, req-type, description).
and an entity can be "branched" from another.
**The idea is to infer that all the attributes that the child entity did not overwrite should be taken from the master entity.**

Here is the existing schema.

```
> database schema test-req-branch
define

description sub attribute,
    value string;

name sub attribute,
    value string;

req-type sub attribute,
    value string;

req-branching sub relation,
    relates branch-item,
    relates branched-from;

requirement sub entity,
    owns description,
    owns name,
    owns req-type,
    plays req-branching:branch-item,
    plays req-branching:branched-from;
```

and the dummy data

```
test-req-branch::data::read> match $e isa entity, has $a;
                             get $e, $a; group $e;
                             
iid 0x826e80018000000000000001 isa requirement => {
    {
        $a "master" isa name;
        $e iid 0x826e80018000000000000001 isa requirement;
    }
    {
        $a "demo master" isa description;
        $e iid 0x826e80018000000000000001 isa requirement;
    }
    {
        $a "whatever" isa req-type;
        $e iid 0x826e80018000000000000001 isa requirement;
    }
}
iid 0x826e80018000000000000000 isa requirement => {
    {
        $a "other" isa name;
        $e iid 0x826e80018000000000000000 isa requirement;
    }
}
answers: 2, total (with concept details) duration: 12 ms


test-req-branch::data::read> match $r (branch-item:$bi, branched-from:$bf)isa req-branching;
                             $bf has name $bfn;
                             $bi has name $bin;
                             
{
    $r iid 0x847080018000000000000000 (branch-item: iid 0x826e80018000000000000000, branched-from: iid 0x826e80018000000000000001) isa req-branching;
    $bf iid 0x826e80018000000000000001 isa requirement;
    $bin "other" isa name;
    $bi iid 0x826e80018000000000000000 isa requirement;
    $bfn "master" isa name;
}
answers: 1, total (with concept details) duration: 8 ms
```

wince the master requirement has (name, req-type, description)
and the child entity "other" has only (name)
I want to infer req-type and description  form the master.

I devised a query that gets the attributes that the child entity does not have.

```
test-req-branch::data::read> match 
                             $rr (branched-from:$rm, branch-item:$cr) isa req-branching;
                             $rm has  $ma;
                             $cr has attribute $ca;
                             $ma isa! $t;
                             not {
                                 $ca isa! $t;
                             };
                             get $ma;
                             
{ $ma "demo master" isa description; }
{ $ma "whatever" isa req-type; }
answers: 2, total (with concept details) duration: 5 ms
```

And I converted this into a rule:

```
rule when-not-defined-attributes-derive-from-parent:
    when
    {
        $rr (branched-from: $rm, branch-item: $cr) isa req-branching;
        $rm has $ma;
        $cr has attribute $ca;
        $ma isa! $t;
        not
        {
            $ca isa! $t;
        };
    }
    then
    {
        $cr has $ma;
    };
```

But when i queried the attributes I got the master's name attached to the child as well.

```
> transaction test-req-branch data read --infer true
test-req-branch::data::read> match $rr (branched-from: $rm, branch-item: $cr) isa req-branching;
                             $cr has $a;
                             get $a;
                             
{ $a "other" isa name; }
{ $a "whatever" isa req-type; }
{ $a "demo master" isa description; }
{ $a "master" isa name; }
answers: 4, total (with concept details) duration: 91 ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

PS: I'm using the typedb docker image:

```
sudo docker ps 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                       NAMES
b8e4d1200059   vaticle/typedb:latest   "/opt/typedb-all-lin…"   4 days ago   Up 4 days   0.0.0.0:1729->1729/tcp, :::1729->1729/tcp   typedb
```

```
./typedb console --version
2.11.0
2.11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

That `match` query is not correct for what you're trying to achieve, which you would have noticed had the `branch-item` had another attribute. I've added `req-type "blah"` to the item, and this is what what I got:

```
test-req-branch::data::read> match
                             $rr (branched-from:$rm, branch-item:$cr) isa req-branching;
                             $rm has  $ma;
                             $cr has attribute $ca;
                             $ma isa! $t;
                             not {
                                 $ca isa! $t;
                             };
                             get $ma;

{ $ma "master" isa name; }
{ $ma "demo master" isa description; }
{ $ma "whatever" isa req-type; }
```

To understand why, let's take a look at what the result of the query looks like before negation.

```
test-req-branch::data::read> match
                             $rr (branched-from:$rm, branch-item:$cr) isa req-branching;
                             $rm has  $ma;
                             $cr has attribute $ca;
                             get $ma, $ca;

{   $ma "whatever" isa req-type;
    $ca "blah" isa req-type; }
{   $ma "master" isa name;
    $ca "blah" isa req-type; }
{   $ma "demo master" isa description;
    $ca "blah" isa req-type; }
{   $ma "whatever" isa req-type;
    $ca "other" isa name; }
{   $ma "master" isa name;
    $ca "other" isa name; }
{   $ma "demo master" isa description;
    $ca "other" isa name; }
```

The negation acts as a sort of filter on all these pairs of attributes `$ca` and `$ma`. If they have different types, i.e. `$ma isa! $t; not { $ca isa! $t; };`, then `$ma` is a valid output. But if `$ca` has two potential types, we're guaranteed to find one that doesn't match `$t`! So we'll get all the attributes of the `branched-from` entity.

A solution would be to tweak the query like so:

```
test-req-branch::data::read> match
                             $rr (branched-from:$rm, branch-item:$cr) isa req-branching;
                             $rm has  $ma;
                             $ma isa! $t;
                             not {
                                 $cr has $ca;
                                 $ca isa! $t;
                             };
                             get $ma;

{ $ma "demo master" isa description; }
```

Here, the negation acts as a filter on `$ma` alone. For each `$ma`, as long as there is at least one `$ca` with the same type, we reject it.

Unfortunately, this won't work as a rule. The negation as part of the query essentially boild the rule down to "if `$cr` does not have an attribute with the type of `$ma`, then it has `$ma`". But that means that it has an attribute with the type of `$ma`, namely, `$ma`! This causes a contradiction (`A cycle containing negation(s) that can cause inference contradictions`), and so the rule is invalid.

P.S. Thanks to Krishnan Govindraj for his help with this answer.